# Internet from personal iphone hotspot not working on macbook air multiple user accounts

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, network, wifi, tethering

I'm using an Iphone SE to create a personal hotspot from my (unlimited) mobile data.

The issue occurs when connecting to this hotspot with my macbook air running High Sierra 10.13.4

When I connect to the hotspot, it works very well on my own user account either by wifi or through usb.

However, when my wife logs in with her personal user account instead (on the same macbook), web pages don't seem to load. She has connected using wifi and usb. In the network setting everything looks to be working properly, however there just doesn't seem to be any data coming in.

Does anybody has any knowledge why this is happening and how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: On the phone there are 2 ways you can use personal hotspot, first if you are logged into the same appleid on both devices the connection is a Automatic, and personal hotspot on the phone can actually be set to on or off and it works.   If both devices are NOT using the same appleid then personal hotspot must be turn ON in setting on the phone, the phone broadcasts an SSID and the MacBook connects to it.  So how do you have it set up?

Comment: @Tyson yes the hotspot was been configured as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually was able to solve this issue by rebooting a couple of times.

Is not the first and will not be the last time an OS issue is resolved by a couple of reboots!